# python encoding

Tags: python, encoding, mechanize

Using `mechanize`, I retrieved source page of an web which contains some non-ASCII characters, such as Chinese characters.

Code goes below:

```
#using python2.6
from mechanize import Browser

br = Browser()
br.open("http://www.example.html")

src = br.reponse().read()  #retrieve the source of the web

print src   #print the src
```

Question:

1.According to the source of the page, I can see that, its `charset=gb2312`, but when I `print src`, all the contents are correct, I mean no gibberish. Why? Does `print` know the src's encoding?

2.Should I explicitly decode or encode the src?

Comment: Print does the encoding for you, according to the encoding scheme of your console. If you want to output the result to file, you need to encode it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`src` is a [`unicode`](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/), which has no encoding. `print` (or more correctly, `sys.stdout.write()`) figures out what encoding to use when outputting.